# Excel VBA to search outlook subject, then save over most recent file on drive

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This may be confusing but here it goes.

I currently have to open outlook search for a title/date "XXX 20130624" and then save over the "template file" that is on the drive with a specified name. ie outlook attachment subject is "ABC 20130624" and the attached excel file is labeled as "ZBA Extra", i then save the attached file on the network as "ABC"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's being asked here?

Comment: I need VBA that i can run from Excel 2007 to go to outlook 2007 inbox, search the for "Subject" then save the attachement of that email to a drive. In excel i have the exact search text for each of the files i need to save (about 19 daily)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step-by-step of what you'll need to do. The code is semi-pseudo-code that won't work out of the box. Ask away on any details that are unclear.

1.0 Get the running instance of Outlook into an object

```
outlook = GetObject( , "Outlook.Application" )
```

2.0 Then access the inbox (olFolderInbox = 6) folder. This has to be done through the Namespace object

```
namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inboxFolder = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
```

3.0 Within this folder, search for the required documents. Your requirements are particularly vague there, I'll assume that any subject ending with a hardcoded date is ok. I'm using DASL syntax here to perform the `like` operator.

```
filter = ""@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0037001f"" = ' 20130628'
items = inboxFolder.Items.Restrict( filter )
```

4.0 Enumerate over the encountered items.

```
For Each item in items
...
Next item
```

4.1. For each item, store the subject, strip off anything from the first space

```
subject = mailItem.Subject
spaceIndex = InStr( subject, " " )
extractFilename = Left( subject, spaceIndex )
```

4.2 Enumerate over the attachments and save them with the name.

```
For Each attachment In Item.Attachments
   fileName = "H:\" & exdtractedFilename & ".xlsx"
   attachment.SaveAsFile fileName
Next attachment
```

Do note that this will overwrite the same file multiple times if there are multiple attachments. You might want to think on how to handle that situation.

Comment: Thank you, i am still looking through it and i will most likley ask more questions.

Comment: I am a complete newbie at this... how do I input the above items to run?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Public Sub Extract_Outlook_Email_Attachments()

    Dim OutlookOpened As Boolean
    Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim outNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim outFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim outAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim outItem As Object
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim outMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim inputDate As String, subjectFilter As String


    saveFolder = "Y:\Wingman" ' THIS IS WHERE YOU WANT TO SAVE THE ATTACHMENT TO

    If Right(saveFolder, 1) <> "\" Then saveFolder = saveFolder & "\"

    subjectFilter = ("Daily Operations Custom All Req Statuses Report") ' THIS IS WHERE YOU PLACE THE EMAIL SUBJECT FOR THE CODE TO FIND

    OutlookOpened = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
        OutlookOpened = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    If outApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot start Outlook.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set outNs = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set outFolder = outNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    If Not outFolder Is Nothing Then
        For Each outItem In outFolder.Items
            If outItem.Class = Outlook.OlObjectClass.olMail Then
                Set outMailItem = outItem
                    If InStr(1, outMailItem.Subject, "subjectFilter") > 0 Then
                        For Each outAttachment In outMailItem.Attachments
                        outAttachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & outAttachment.filename

                        Set outAttachment = Nothing

                        Next
                    End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If OutlookOpened Then outApp.Quit

    Set outApp = Nothing

    End Sub
```